# JavaScript function parameter question: How are parameters used when there is no argument?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JavaScript, and I can never find an explanation to this in the tutorials I have gone through.

This example function calculates the length of user names.

My question is: How does "name" work in the function? It seems to be completely arbitrary what I call it, and how exactly does it work? In all explanations of functions I've gone through, the function parameter is used when the function is called with an argument, but there is nothing like that here.

It seems to me like "name.length" works like "users.length", but I don't understand why it's written like this.

```
const users = ['Nathan', 'John', 'William'];

const nameLengths = users.map(function(name) {
   return name.length;
});

console.log(nameLengths);
```

Comment: The function passed in `Array#map` is a callback which is executed for every item in `array` and currentValue is being used as `name` in this example.

Comment: `map` calls your function.

Comment: You can go through [map polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) to understand how it is working

Comment: `map` is irrelevant, I could have made the example with another method. I'm wondering, how does this parameter get it's data?

Comment: It gets its data when it's "called back", once for (and with) each value in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function inside `map` is known as an anonymous function because it has no name. If you see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the argument list for the callback is:

```
currentValue[, index[, array]][, thisArg]
```

So `map`'s callback function takes the `currentValue` each time it runs - in your code, this is called `name`. It gets its data because `map` is a glorified `for` loop with a couple of extra features - you could write your code like this if you like:

```js
const users = ['Nathan', 'John', 'William'];

let name;
let nameLengths = [];

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  name = users[i];
  nameLengths.push(name.length);
}

console.log(nameLengths);
```

But `map` is easier - plus, it shows that the array is being modified/mutated, because that's the primary role of `map`. A better version of the above would be:

```js
const users = ['Nathan', 'John', 'William'];

const cb = name => name.length;

let name;
let nameLengths = [];

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  name = users[i];
  nameLengths.push(cb(name));
}

console.log(nameLengths);
```

In the above code, you can clearly see the different parts of `map` - `cb` is the anonymous function that accepts `name` as a parameter and returns `name.length`, and you can also kind of see how `map` is pretty much a `for` loop/

Comment: Also I was using `const` because the OP was using `const` - I would have used `let`.

Answer (score 1):

That's an anonymous function, with `name` being its parameter. The `map` method "feeds" the function with each array element as it iterates through the `users` array.

Comment: I know that `name` is the parameter, but how does it get it's data?

Comment: I've explained it in the second sentence - the function gets called for each array element.